# Is energy lost in an elastic tunneling process?

Tags: quantum-tunneling

Suppose we had two metal plates separated by an Angstrom.  Now, apply a voltage $V$ between the two metal plates.  There will be a tunneling current $I$ between the metal plates.

Since $P=IV$, does that imply power is being dissipated by the system, even if the tunneling is elastic?

Some additional thoughts: Perhaps this is related to why there is still resistance in ballistic transport.

Comment: if it is quantum mechanical tunneling you are talking about energy should not be lost. have a look at http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/barr.html .

Comment: @annav Yes, I am talking about quantum mechanical tunneling.  And yes, if the tunneling is elastic, electrons will tunnel from one state to another of the same energy.  However, $P=IV$ indicates that energy will be lost at some point.

Comment: can you give a link for P=IV ? I suspect it comes from classical considerations. Quantum mechanically there is no energy loss in the tunneling. There may be in the rest of the circuit which has to exist for a current to form and which is adequately described by classical formulae with resistances etc where the power will be lost..